# C# - Copying files and resume support

Tags: c#, stream, copy, filestream, resume

Hi
Does anyone have workable sample code that copy files and support resuming them if there are the source has been disconnected?

In this example I am copying videos files. If the source is disconnected ie usb was unplugged, how can I support resuming them again? I have tried some code on stackoverflow, but after resuming, the video files seem to be corrupted. Is FileStream the best solution for video transfers/resume?

Any other pointers or tips are welcome.

```
private void CreateNewCopyTo(FileStream source, FileStream dest) {
  int size = (source.CanSeek) ? Math.Min((int)(source.Length - source.Position), 0x2000) : 0x2000;
  byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
  int read;
  long fileLength = source.Length;
  while ((read = source.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) {
    dest.Write(buffer, 0, read);
    dest.Close();
    dest = new FileStream(dest.Name, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
  }
  dest.Close();
}

private void ResumeCopyTo(FileStream source, FileStream dest) {
  int size = (source.CanSeek) ? Math.Min((int)(source.Length - source.Position), 0x2000) : 0x2000;
  byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
  long TempPos = source.Position;
  while (true) {
    int read = source.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    if (read <= 0)
      return;
    dest.Write(buffer, 0, read);
    dest.Close();
    dest = new FileStream(dest.Name, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to insert `source.Seek(dest.Length, SeekOrigin.Begin);` as first line in ResumeCopyTo method.

Comment: do you think this is a good method of copying data? or there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: The idea is true, but the realization is not so good. It would be good to use hash, read/write by blocks, do not recreate stream every time etc. And in real project you should write a good abstraction for this system.

Answer (score 1):

create a file that is the same size as the file your copying. And if the connection is broken write a "BookMark" into the file. Some arbitrary string at the end of the file that tells you where you  left off.

Best to get a hash of the original file to determine if the file has changed since the last copy attempt. (if the file is different then you should check the data in the destination with the data in the source, perhaps with another hash of the data.)

The most important part tho is to seek in the source and the destination to the exact same point in both files. before the resume attempt.

You will want to make sure that your seek will give you the next byte in the source file. Not the same byte you left off at. Otherwise you will be left with your data having a single duplicate character. Which will corrupt the data.

(e.g. if the source file is 12345678901234567890 and your destination made it to 123456 , you dont want to resume at 6, you want to resume at 7. otherwise your destination would be 123456678901234567890)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the file does not change in time, we can use the functions that you have written. However, they should be slightly modified and simplified to one function.

```
    private void ResumeCopy(FileStream source, FileStream dest)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[0x10000]; //use 64kB buffer
        int read;

        source.Seek(dest.Length, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        while ((read = source.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            dest.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            dest.Flush();
        }
    }
```

We can create an additional function:

```
    private void ResumeCopyTo(string sourceFilePath, string destFilePath)
    {
        FileStream input = new FileStream(sourceFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        FileStream output = new FileStream(destFilePath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);

        ResumeCopy(input, output);

        output.Close();
        input.Close();
    }
```

Ideas for a production environment:

- add error handling
- check whether the file has changed (use checksum)
- opened the source file in exclusive mode

BTW:
In this way, I copied an 15 GB file in 9 hours via a network connection of really poor quality.